# Why not all properties in ClassifierMeasurements are available?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm doing an experiment of objects classification on dataset CIFAR-10 and I'm doing this using a neural network. The basic code of this experiment is come from the demo on Mathematica website and I tried to add a part of evaluating the classifier I trained.

I used CNN as a classifier and this is what it look like:

```
    lenet = NetChain[ {ConvolutionLayer[20, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2],        ConvolutionLayer[50, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2], FlattenLayer[], 500, Ramp, 2, SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", classes}], "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {32, 32}}] ]
```

After training, I created a ClassifierMeasurementsObject using function ClassifierMeasurements:

```
    cm=ClassifierMeasurements[trained,testData]
```

where trained is the name of trained CNN module.

Then I use this code to see what I can do with the ClassifierMeasurementsObject:

```
    cm["Properties"]
```

and I got the output:

```
    {Accuracy, AccuracyRejectionPlot, ClassRejectionRate,   ConfusionFunction, ConfusionMatrix, ConfusionMatrixPlot, Error, FScore, InversePerplexity, Likelihood, LogLikelihood, Perplexity, Precision, Properties, Recall, RejectionRate}
```

what I got from the output is much less than the document for ClassifierMeasurements, something missed such as "AreaUnderROCCurve", "CorrectlyClassifiedExamples", "Examples",  {"Examples",i->j},  "WorstClassifiedExamples", etc.

I don't know why would this happen. Is this because the algorithm I use or the dataset I use? Do I have any way to find and split out all the misclassified samples?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you add a link to where you see the missing properties? I don't see "AreaUnderROCCurve" in the documentation.

Comment: @xslittlegrass ,please see here, in the document of ClassifierMeasurements, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClassifierMeasurements.html and here, the document of ClassifierMeasurementsObject, which is the output of ClassifierMeasurement,http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClassifierMeasurementsObject.html

Comment: I'm still not seeing "AreaUnderROCCurve", could you point out the exact place in the documentation? Thanks.

Comment: @xslittlegrass In the both documents, under the basic description of the functions' parameters, there is a hidden menu titled by "more information and options", and you can see the hidden content after clicking it, where you can find all the properties.

Comment: I find the properties such as `{"Examples",i->j}`, `"Accuracy"`, ` "AccuracyRejectionPlot"`, etc. in "Details and Options", but I don't see the "AreaUnderROCCurve" property in there.